# How to protect file from multiple perl application access?

Tags: perl

I have a  /root/abc/sample.xml file and this file is being accessed by many other application (around 2000 applications) parallel. so can you please suggest me any mechanism to access this file very safely /root/abc/sample.xml by all the application without any file corruption. I am beginner in perl programming .

Each application will read this file and close it once the process is done.

Comment: If all of them just read from the file (and do not write), there will be no problem. You can set file permissions to read-only to make sure.

Comment: Yes, i need only read operation. I thought reading this sample.xml same time by multiple application will cause issue.

Comment: You don't need any protection if files are only read. Otherwise you'll need shared locks before reading and exclusive locks before writing to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are file locking solutions available with this in mind; [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) is one. It provides a file lock ( `flock()` ) method that waits for a file to be free and then locks it, and unlock ( `unlock()` ).

For you example you could do;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

# import LOCK_* and SEEK_END constants
use Fcntl qw(:flock SEEK_END);

# Open the file
open(my $xml, ">>", "sample.xml") or die "Can't open xml $!";

# Lock the file
flock($xml, LOCK_EX) or die "Cannot lock xml - $!\n";

# Someone may have changed the file while waiting for lock
# Either re-read or seek to end depening on what your doing.
# We are just going to append some stuff so will seek to end
# for this example
seek($xml, 0, SEEK_END) or die "Cannot seek - $!\n";

# Do some stuff
print $xml "<foo>bar</foo>" ,"\n\n";

# Unlock
flock($xml, LOCK_UN) or die "Cannot unlock xml - $!\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of your applications just read from the file (and do not write), there will be no problem. You can set file permissions to read-only to make sure.

Data corruption is only an issue if at least one party tries to update the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you require write access, you can also use locks (file locking) or a distributed locking service like ZooKeeper + the Net::ZooKeeper module(possibly overkill).